# Dynamically check dynamic checkboxes from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have some dynamically created checkboxes, creating using this bit of PHP:

```
<?php do { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="Cat_Ref_Array[]" value="<?php echo $row_selectCategories['Cat_Ref']; ?>" />
<label for="Category"><?php echo $row_selectCategories['Category']; ?></label>
<?php } while ($row_selectCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectCategories)); ?>
```

I also have a another table with possible responses saved, which is retrieved like so:

```
$query_getFeatureCat = sprintf("SELECT `Ref`, Cat_Ref, dist FROM newtable WHERE `Ref` = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_getFeatureCat, "text"));
$getFeatureCat = mysql_query($query_getFeatureCat, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getFeatureCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFeatureCat);
```

How can I get the form to prepopulate/"check" the checkboxes when the checkbox `value` appears in the output from the `newtable` lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$query_getFeatureCat = sprintf("SELECT `Ref`, Cat_Ref, dist FROM newtable WHERE `Ref` = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_getFeatureCat, "text"));
$getFeatureCat = mysql_query($query_getFeatureCat, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getFeatureCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($getFeatureCat);
while ($row_selectCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectCategories)) {
  if ($row_getFeatureCat) {
    if (in_array($row_selectCategories['Cat_Ref'], $row_getFeatureCat)) {
      $checked = 'checked';
    } ?>
  }
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cat_Ref_Array[]" value="<?php echo $row_selectCategories['Cat_Ref']; ?>"  <?php echo $checked; ?>/>
  <label for="Category"><?php echo $row_selectCategories['Category']; ?></label>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Definitely getting warmer! Now I get this: `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given`. Any advice?

Comment: That must be because the first query didn't return any result or reached end of array.

Comment: I'm so sorry, Alfred, but I don't follow. Can you explain it to me? Without the lookup from `newtable`, the checkboxes all appear fine from the `Categories` table. It's only when I try to combine them that I get the error

Comment: @user1259798 I have edited the code to check whether the variable $row_getFeatureCat actually contains db result. Can you please check now?